# How to keep my backbone router DRY

Tags: backbone.js, router

I've got a router which serves up most of my main pages from a single route.

```
'myclasses/:id':'index',
'myclasses': 'index',
'classes/:id':'index',
'index':''
```

This all works pretty well, but the problem I'm having is that I need to figure out if the request came from `myclasses` or from `classes` as that will return a different result which I pass to my collection.

How can I get the requesting url, preferably without the :id, from within the index function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Backbone.history.fragment.

Comment: the history fragment gives me the route which has been pointed to, not the url, so I end up with 'index' for all of them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SBhTy/
it seems to work like it should for me. I suppose you were at the index, is that possible?

Comment: you are correct. I had used somebody elses code where they had `this.routes[Backbone.history.fragment]`, but just using `Backbone.history.fragment` without `this.routes` is the correct answer. thanks for taking the time to sort me out.